# How to change between python, pascal, and javascript language easily in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pascal, freepascal

I just learned programming, and I just installed vscode. Can I change between programming languages easily? And how to run Pascal programming in it?

Comment: create different launch configurations, to run Pascal use your Pascal compiler in a Build Task

Answer (score 0):

You can just write your files, and vscode will handle everything for you, as it has a very good understanding of file associations.

The only things that might be confusing are when using f5 for example to run your code.

You can set what happens when pressing f5 (Debug) and control shift b (build)by altering the tasks defined in tasks.json.

To find this file, go to your command pallet (f1 or control shift p), and search for `Tasks: Open User Tasks`.

There's a link in that file to the schema docs.

I think the file is saved in the .vscode folder at the root of your project's directory.